# How to get Apple News App in iPhone 5 (India)

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, iphone, news.app

I have iPhone 5 and iOS 9.2 installed right now in my phone but still i am not getting Apple News app in my phone.

Can any one let me know how can I get that application on my iPhone 5 (India).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: [iOS 9 Feature Availability § News](http://www.apple.com/ios/feature-availability/#news)

> News is only available in Australia, USA, and the UK.

This is also more "explicitly" stated in the fine print at the end of the [iOS 9.3 Preview](http://www.apple.com/ios/preview/) page.

> Features are subject to change.
>
> 1. News is available only in the U.S., UK, and Australia.
> 2. May not be available in all regions.